# How to start a new bash REPL with executing a script

Tags: bash, shell, read-eval-print-loop

I have a script `foo.sh` with some functions I'd like to test in a bash REPL, and for some reason I need to do this in a new bash REPL instead of sourcing it in the current shell, that is:

1. Open up a new bash REPL
2. Source `foo.sh` in the new-opened REPL

Is there such a way to do that in one command, like in `python -i foo.py` or `ghci foo.hs`? I have tried `bash -i "foo.sh"`, `bash -c "source foo.sh"`, `bash -c "$(cat foo.sh)"` etc., but all of them seem to just execute the script and then immediately exit.

Comment: By "bash REPL", do you mean just a regular interactive shell, or something else?

Comment: @GordonDavisson just a regular interactive shell.

Comment: Maybe `bash --rcfile foo.sh` !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use process substitution to source both .bashrc and foo.sh :

```
bash --rcfile <(cat ~/.bashrc; cat foo.sh) -i
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `--init-file` option to do this (along with the `-i` option to mark the shell as interactive):

```
bash bash --init-file foo.sh -i
```

Note that `-i` must come after `--init-file` (and the filename).

Comment: Is it possible to include `.bashrc` at the same time?

Comment: @Futarimiti Not that I know of. But you could add `[ -e ~/.bashrc ] && . ~/.bashrc` to the beginning of your init file. (Or, I suppose if that's not an option, make a wrapper script that sources both ~/.bashrc *and* the additional file you want to source.)

Answer (score 0):

```
bash -c ". foo.sh && bash"
```

### Example

`foo.sh`:

```
export TEST=MORE
```

Then run:

```
> bash -c ". foo.sh && bash"
> echo $SHLVL # shows how many shell levels we are down; 
2             # 2 because of the first and second `bash`
> echo $TEST
MORE          # yes, environment was sourced
```

PS: you could just run `. foo.sh && bash` but that would change your current environment, which, I assume, is what you want to avoid.

Comment: `exec bash` instead of `bash` at the end to not have an extra bash process hanging around for no reason.

Comment: You can also use a subshell for the sourcing: `(. foo.sh && exec bash)`.

Comment: Much thanks, but it seems only `export` variables and functions are recognised. Is it possible to expose everything to the REPL?